# How to set database login infos (connection info) for crystal report vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I am having a little problem getting Crystal Reports to set the logon.  I have it working in a number of reports but a couple for some reason have stopped working.  Attached is my logon script, I have stepped through it and the logon info is all there after every step.
What is even more unusual is that the report in visual studio will open with information OK

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrint.Click
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    Dim crTableLogonInfos As New TableLogOnInfos
    Dim crTableLogonInfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    Dim crTables As Tables
    Dim crTable As Table
    cryRpt.Load("g:\dt2\rptMusterSheet.rpt")
    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = "SERVERNAME"
        .DatabaseName = "DB NAME"
        .UserID = "sa"
        .Password = "xxxxxxx"
    End With
    crTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
    For Each crTable In crTables
        crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo)
    Next
    CRV1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    CRV1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

after stepping through I get this[Message Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMIcp.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
Dim mytableloginfos As New TableLogOnInfos()
mytableloginfos = CRV1.LogOnInfo
For Each myTableLogOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo In mytableloginfos
    myTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply but I am not sure where to put that, I have placed the code under the crTables = cryRpt.logOnInfo and commented out the original for each statement but myTableLogonInfo has been underlined and error message "Variable myTableLogOnInfo hide as variable in enclosing block"