# VB.NET application with MySQL DSN connection for Crystal Reports asks for Logon info

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have an application written in VB.NET. 
It was written for a client some time ago on 32 bit architecture. 
The database is MySQL 5.5. 
The reports were inbuilt Crystal reports and the database connectivity was ODBC 32bit MySQL connector through a DSN.

Now the client has upgraded all the clients to windows 10(64bit).
The desktop application works well with the same old 32bit connector, but when any report is run, it asks for a logon screen. Unfortunately, passing the login credentials at run-time doesn't work.

The code is as attached. I have browsed through all the answers, but the codes don't work. Is there something I am missing? Can anyone help?
I know the issue is an old one, but it is a running application for some years and we don't really need to rewrite.

Code: (Called on a button link)

```
 Public Sub PrintAmcRemainderForIndus(ByVal componentId As Integer, ByVal AddressId As Integer)         
   'Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        Dim rPath As String = ""
        Dim objForm As New frmViewReport
    rPath = Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\rptAMCReminderForIndus.rpt"'
    MessageBox.Show(rPath.Length & vbCrLf & rPath)
    Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos()
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo()
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim CrTable As Table
    Dim TableCounter

    Dim cryRpt As New rptAMCReminderForIndus()


    'If you are using ODBC, this should be the DSN name NOT the physical server name. If
    'you are NOT using ODBC, this should be the
    'physical server name

    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = "Indus"

        'If you are connecting to Oracle there is no
        'DatabaseName. Use an empty string.
        'For example, .DatabaseName = ""

        .DatabaseName = "indus"
        .UserID = "root"
        .Password = "simsoft"
    End With

    'This code works for both user tables and stored
    'procedures. Set the CrTables to the Tables collection
    'of the report
    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables


    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next

    Try

        'cryRpt.Load(rPath)

        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

        crParameterValues.Clear()

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = componentId
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("piCustomerId")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = AddressId
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("piAddressId")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        objForm.rptViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt
        objForm.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.InnerException.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is something wrong here:

```
'If you are using ODBC, this should be the DSN name NOT the physical server name. If
'you are NOT using ODBC, this should be the
'physical server name

With crConnectionInfo
    .ServerName = "Indus"
```

Are you sure you are providing the name of the ODBC, not the hostname?

Have a look here:

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4870

and here:

[How to set database login infos (connection info) for crystal report vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419759/how-to-set-database-login-infos-connection-info-for-crystal-report-vb-net)